# unexpected error on gae when test on local machine

Tags: google-app-engine

I am really new on gae, but I have a task that have to deploy on google.
because I don't know how to stop after `sudo /usr/local/bin/dev_appserver.py`, I just press control+c. after a while, when I tried to deploy again, I receive following message:

```
INFO     2016-04-03 00:42:40,222 sdk_update_checker.py:229] Checking for updates to the SDK.
INFO     2016-04-03 00:42:41,272 api_server.py:205] Starting API server at: http://localhost:51277
INFO     2016-04-03 00:42:41,275 api_server.py:648] Applying all pending transactions and saving the datastore
INFO     2016-04-03 00:42:41,275 api_server.py:651] Saving search indexes
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/dev_appserver.py", line 83, in <module>
    _run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "/usr/local/bin/dev_appserver.py", line 79, in _run_file
    execfile(_PATHS.script_file(script_name), globals_)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/devappserver2.py", line 1040, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/devappserver2.py", line 1033, in main
    dev_server.start(options)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/devappserver2.py", line 824, in start
    self._dispatcher.start(options.api_host, apis.port, request_data)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/dispatcher.py", line 194, in start
    _module.start()
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/module.py", line 1176, in start
    self._balanced_module.start()
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/wsgi_server.py", line 315, in start
    self._start_all_fixed_port(host_ports)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/wsgi_server.py", line 352, in _start_all_fixed_port
    raise BindError('Unable to bind %s:%s' % self.bind_addr)
google.appengine.tools.devappserver2.wsgi_server.BindError: Unable to bind localhost:8080
```

so far, I tried reinstall gaelauncher, but it doesn't work.
please, any help would be good.

Comment: You could have a look at some of the answers in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15985130/apps-wont-run-on-gae-unable-to-bind-to-localhost0
Basically you need to find the process using the port and end it.

Answer (score 0):

After a few days, it worked again. I think it is Google App Engine's thing and I don't know its reason so far. But if you just want to use the deploy-on-localhost function, please step to other tools, it will be easier. Suggestion: MAMP.