# Google AppEngine - updating my webapp after deploy

Tags: python, google-app-engine, deployment, sdk, webapp2

friends! 
I'm fairly new to web app world and I have a question regarding Google AppEngine functions. 
I've installed the Launcher on my machine and signed up for the online platform (Python). I've added my project folder in the Launcher and hit "deploy" to have it online. However, when I edit/update my "main.py" file to move forward in the development the edits are not reflected online. In other words: I don't see any change, when I go to the link: [NAME].appspot.com  and in fact, checking at the *source code*, I can see that it is still the first version I've developed. :(Shouldn't it update with em just saving the new .py version?  Maybe it's a quite simple step I'm missing, but would be absolutely great if someone could help me :)

Extra info: I'm using Python 2.7 and have the SDK.

THANKS!!
-Valentina

Answer (score 0):

Local changes are immediately reflected only on the local development server. From the [Make a change](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/quickstart#make_a_change) section of [Quickstart for Python App Engine Standard Environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/quickstart):

> Make a change
>
> You can leave the development server running while you develop your
>   application. The development server watches for changes in your source
>   files and reloads them if necessary.
>
> 1. Try it now: Leave the development server running, then edit `main.py` to change `Hello, World!` to something else.
> 2. Reload http://localhost:8080/ to see the results.

The deployment step **is** what updates the live app. You need to repeat it whenever you want the latest code changes reflected by the live app. From [Deploying a Python App](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadinganapp):

> Deploy your app to upload and run them on App Engine. When you deploy
>   your apps, you create versions of those apps and their corresponding
>   [services](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/an-overview-of-app-engine#versions_and_instances) in App Engine.

Comment: Thank you, Dan! I still have some issue and I think they might be also related to my settings. For instance I can see my webapp when on: [NAME].appspot.com, but I can connect to: http://localhost:8080/. Do you know how I can fix this? I'm using Mac OS El Capitan. Thanks so much!!!

Comment: Sorry, I fail to understand from your comment what is the "this" that you're trying to fix.

Comment: Hi Dan! Let me try to explain better: I hit deploy and then hit the green button "Run" in the GAELauncher. Here is the error message I am receiving:                                                                                                       raise BindError('Unable to bind %s:%s' % self.bind_addr)
google.appengine.tools.devappserver2.wsgi_server.BindError: Unable to bind localhost:8080

Comment: You seem to keep trying to do thing backwards: typically you first do Run (until you're happy with how your code runs locally, on the devserver) **then** you deploy that code on GAE. You only need to Run once, the server keeps running until you stop it (or it dies for some reason). Attempting to run again when the server is already running will fail with that error message. Same message can be seen if something else is running and listening to that port. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15985130/apps-wont-run-on-gae-unable-to-bind-to-localhost0 for example.

Comment: Hi Dan! Thanks for your answer. I followed your steps, changed the port to a different localhost, but still getting the same error message. might that be something on my settings?

Comment: Sorry, I can't visualize what going on. My advice - forget (for now) about deploying and seeing the app working on GAE, focus on getting it working on your local devserver first.